# How to redirect full domain URL and remove subfolder using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect the following in my Apaches `.htaccess` file from 
`http://example1.com/folder/index.php` to `http://example2.com/index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?siteone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder(/.*)?$ http://www.sitetwo.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, This is how i modified your suggestion to work for me

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://siteone.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.siteone.com$
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder(.*)$ http://sitetwo.com$1

Much appreciated

Comment: No you cannot match RewriteCond with RedirectMatch. What happens when you use my suggested line alone? Are there any existing rules already?

Comment: Yes this is the full solution I used, `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^siteone.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.siteone.com$
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder(.*)$ http://www.sitetwo.com$1`

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.